# python tkinter update content of a label when a file is opened

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently programming a GUI using tkinter and Python 3.
My problem here is i made a Label with which i want to display the path of a file i opened via the `askopenfilename()` method and this path is not "generated" when i start the program, obviously, so the Label is empty which makes sense but i don't know how to fix it.
I'm gonna put the needed code below (I'm going to cut unnecessary code for this question):

```
import tkinter as tk

class Graphicaluserinterface(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.fileopenname=tk.StringVar()
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.inputpathdisplay = tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.fileopenname,bg="white",width=30)
        self.inputpathdisplay.grid(row=1,column=8,columnspan=3,sticky = "W")
    def fileopening(self):
        from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
        self.fileopenname = askopenfilename(filetypes = [("binary files","*.bin*"),("all files","*.*")])


root = tk.Tk()
app = Graphicaluserinterface(master=root)
root.config(menu=app.menubar)
app.mainloop()
```

I read about using `update_idletasks()`. If this is correct in my case how would i go about implementing it here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you are doing `self.fileopenname = askopenfilename()` and this will redefine `self.fileopenname` as a string instead of a StringVar(). To correct this you need to set the value of StringVar with `set()`.

That said you should also define all your imports at the top of your code instead of in your function.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


class Graphicaluserinterface(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.fileopenname=tk.StringVar()
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)

        self.inputpathdisplay = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.fileopenname, bg="white")
        self.inputpathdisplay.grid(row=1,column=8,columnspan=3,sticky = "W")
        self.fileopening()

    def fileopening(self):
        self.fileopenname.set(askopenfilename(filetypes = [("binary files","*.bin*"),("all files","*.*")]))


root = tk.Tk()
app = Graphicaluserinterface(master=root)
root.config(menu=app.menubar)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks alot it worked out for me and it changes everytime i select a new file. Can u eloborate on why i don´t need update_idletasks()? I thought when i change something in the program window the mainloop even has to be updated for it to show itself in the window, so why did it work in my case?

Comment: The `mainloop()` updates on its own. Tkinter is event driven and `mainloop()` is like one big loop. So after each event executes it loops over again while updating visuals.

Comment: oh ok that cleared things up for me, so i guess i need update_idletasks only for changed that occur before the event is finished

Comment: @James honestly I have never used it myself. I am sure it has its purpose but its not likely all that necessary.

Comment: on another topic, will i be able to use this variable for other methods like using it as a name for a file i create, because print(self.fileopenname) will give me "PY_VAR75"

Comment: nevermind, when using print(self.fileopenname.get()) it works fine

Comment: @James yep. For something like `StringVar`, `IntVar` and the other `Var`'s you need to use `set()` to change their value and `get()` to get a string of their value.